# How to make an indicator mark highs of red candles only if the high is higher than all previous opens

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Bar Test", overlay=true)

// User Inputs
lineColor = input(color.rgb(255, 255, 255), "Line Color")
lineWidth = input(2, "Line Width")
priceLabelColor = input(color.rgb(239, 250, 87), "Price Label Color")
showPriceLabel = input(true, "Show Price Label")

[pOpenWeekly, pCloseWeekly, pHighWeekly] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', [open, close, high])

for i = 1 to 100
    if close[0] > open[0]
        isBearishCandle = pCloseWeekly[i] < pOpenWeekly[i] and pHighWeekly[i] > close[0]
        if isBearishCandle 
            lineObj = line.new(x1=bar_index[i], y1=pHighWeekly[i], x2=bar_index, y2=pHighWeekly[i], color=lineColor, width=lineWidth, extend=extend.both, style=line.style_solid)

            if showPriceLabel
                prices = label.new(x=bar_index[i], y=pHighWeekly[i], text=str.tostring(pHighWeekly[i], "#.##"), color=priceLabelColor, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small)
                label.set_x(prices, bar_index + 20)
    if open[0] > close[0]
        isBearishCandle = pCloseWeekly[i] < pOpenWeekly[i] and pHighWeekly[i] > open[0]
        if isBearishCandle 
            lineObj = line.new(x1=bar_index[i], y1=pHighWeekly[i], x2=bar_index, y2=pHighWeekly[i], color=lineColor, width=lineWidth, extend=extend.both, style=line.style_solid)

            if showPriceLabel
                prices = label.new(x=bar_index[i], y=pHighWeekly[i], text=str.tostring(pHighWeekly[i], "#.##"), color=priceLabelColor, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small)
                label.set_x(prices, bar_index + 20)
```

This is currently marking the highs and labeling the prices of all red candles within a hundred bars on the weekly. However, I'd like to be able to only mark them if they are higher than all previous opens.

Also, sometimes there is weird stuff that happens like this:[image: Candles not being marked]

The first few candles aren't marked for some reason, I can't figure this out.

And this happens when I want to view it on the 1 minute:[image: All lines condensed into one line]

For some reason it all gets condensed into one weird line, not sure how to go about fixing this either.